# How to change default vendor name for "composer init" command

Tags: composer-php

I have an issue when I create a new composer package.
For instance when I start creating the package, I create an empty folder and then I run **composer init**.

Then, Composer propose me already a default value for the Package name.
In this case:

```
Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [namesurname/testdirectory]
```

But since in Github my username has a - in between. I need to change my vendor name from **namesurname** to **name-surname**.

I'm checking on the composer documentation if there is a setting in the composer configuration to change the **vendor name** but I cannot find anything about.

How can I change it?

Comment: Just type `name-surname/testdirectory`? This is prompt with `namesurname/testdirectory` as default value.

Comment: I would love to change the default setting, so I just need to press enter to confirm the Package name, without typing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `COMPOSER_DEFAULT_VENDOR` environment variable to set default vendor name:

```
export COMPOSER_DEFAULT_VENDOR=name-surname
composer init
```

You may add `export COMPOSER_DEFAULT_VENDOR=name-surname` to your `.bashrc` to make it permanent.

AFAIK it is undocumented, but it was implemented in [this PR](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/6548).